# Boostrap 5 toast on page load

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the code below to show a toast on page load in HTML and JS,

```
    <!-- Toast -->

  <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="toast-header">
    <img src="..." class="rounded me-2" alt="...">
    <strong class="me-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
    <small>11 mins ago</small>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
    Hello, world! This is a toast message.
   </div>
  </div>


<script>

window.onload = (event) => {
let myAlert = document.querySelectorAll('.toast');
let bsAlert = new bootstrap.Toast(myAlert);
bsAlert.show();
  5}
 </script>
```

but nothing is showing on page load, hope you can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns multiple elements, you just want one element for `bootstrap.Toast`. I've created a snippet of your code with a slight modification, i.e. getting the first `.toast` and then checking it exists.

```js
window.onload = (event) => {
  let myAlert = document.querySelectorAll('.toast')[0];
  if (myAlert) {
    let bsAlert = new bootstrap.Toast(myAlert);
    bsAlert.show();
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
  <div class="toast-header">
    <img src="..." class="rounded me-2" alt="...">
    <strong class="me-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
    <small>11 mins ago</small>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="toast-body">
    Hello, world! This is a toast message.
  </div>
</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```